# How can i link WinPcap to my go program?

Tags: go, gcc, cgo, winpcap

I downloaded [WinPcap](https://www.winpcap.org/install/bin/WpdPack_4_1_2.zip) and extracted all the files to my `C:\` drive, and did all the things described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38047858/compile-gopacket-on-windows-64bit).

Then, I added the CGO directives to my `main.go` and built the program with "go build".

I'm doing all this on windows. but windows totally ignores these directives.

If I start the program, **it crashes because `wpcap.dll is missing`**.

Here are my directives:

```
// #cgo solaris LDFLAGS: -L /opt/local/lib -lpcap
// #cgo linux LDFLAGS: -lpcap
// #cgo dragonfly LDFLAGS: -lpcap
// #cgo freebsd LDFLAGS: -lpcap
// #cgo openbsd LDFLAGS: -lpcap
// #cgo darwin LDFLAGS: -lpcap
// #cgo windows CFLAGS: -I C:/WpdPack/Include
// #cgo windows,386 LDFLAGS: -L C:/WpdPack/Lib -lwpcap
// #cgo windows,amd64 LDFLAGS: -L C:/WpdPack/Lib/x64 -lwpcap
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include <pcap.h>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sry i forgot to mention that i want to use gopacket in my program. but i cant start it if no wpcap.dll is unter system32-Folder. it just crashes

Comment: even if i build all this in linux (cross compiling) the program crashes if the dll is missing? is it possible to solve that?

Comment: it seems to be impossible. elastic beats (packet analyzer) also need winpcap preinstalled!